# How do we 'watch ' atomic interactions?

Tags: radiation

I'm relatively new to objective physics and it's measuring and imaging abilities.. Specifically I don't know if we can 'watch' inter/or intra molecular exchanges like the photonic and electronic.
I also wonder about phononic vibrational exchanges..

If we can't 'watch' the exchange electromagnetically and/or otherwise directly, there must be other ways to infer the amplitudes and frequencies, right?

Comment: Photomultiplier tubes can detect single photons with good quantum efficiency, and so can CCDs (even though the readout noise of a CCD is higher than a single photon). Phonons can be detected with optical and other methods (e.g. tunnel junctions), but I am not sure about the sensitivity at the quantum level.

Comment: Thank you, I know I'm asking a lot between three separate topics, but I want a lot. I'm recognizing that our measurement techniques construct our perspective, so their accuracy and such is greatly important!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. The phonon model can be validated indirectly by measuring specific heat, conductivity etc.. Even though we can visualize phonon modes on many systems just fine, the individual phonon measurement tells us nothing about the thermodynamic quantities. It's only the self-consistence of many different types of observations that can validate a physical model or theory. The "tick" on a single instrument does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Youre thinking too hard mate! I'm opening inquiry into the few ways we choose to conceptualize these interactions, and so: why. Of course the tick matters! It means something is there where it wasn't before!